# Diamond Sort in MIPS/C

Tags: c, mips

Say we have a diamond (85 elements in a 13*13 array)
Every element has two parameters, a/b
We need to sort the diamond so that:

1. the [a] parameter increases in each column.
2. the [b] parameter increases in each row.

What we want to get is like this: (the * is the part that is not defined in memory)

(this is an easy one 13 elements in a 5*5 array)

original:

```
*    *   4/3   *   *
*   1/3  2/3  4/5  *
1/2 3/1  2/5  3/6 2/7
*   2/3  1/2  5/2  *
*    *   6/1   *   *
```

sorted:

```
*    *   1/3   *   *
*   1/2  2/3  2/5  *
1/2 2/3  4/5  3/6 2/7
*   3/1  5/2  4/3  *
*    *   6/1   *   *
```

My algorithm is to bubble sort (according to a) all the values, then sort in each line according to the b parameter. This works pretty good but the dynamic instructions would be over 80000 (which should be O[n^2]). The bubble sort sucks hard in MIPS 'cause you need >10 instr. for each check (in bubble).

I want to know if there is better algorithm that reduces the dynamic instructions under 14000. BTW only use <=15 register and <=66 static instructions (which is 66 lines of code).

```
findnum:    addi    $27, $27, 4
            lw  $21, 0($27)
            beq $21, $0, findnum    # find the next nonzero number


bsort:      lw  $20, 0($25)             # load first number            
            slt $12, $21, $20       # if second < first $12=1
            bne $12, $15,  back     # $15 is constant 1
            sw  $21, 0($25)
            sw  $20, 0($27)
back:       addi    $25, $27, 0     # now second number is first number
            bne $27, $26, findnum   # $27 not the end then continue         



loop:       addi    $25, $01, 24
            addi    $27, $25, 0     # reinitialize the number
            addi    $10, $10, 1     # i++
            bne     $10, $11, findnum   # if i not equal to 85 jump back
```

This is the core part of my code. $25 and $27 are initialized as the address of the first value of the array. $26 is the address of the last value.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One approach that allows you to evide the 2D structure is to transform your values, fill them into a 1D array, sort them, fill them back to 2D and transform them back.

So with your simplified example, this: `4/3` would become the number: `403` by this transformation:

```
n(x/y) = 100*x + y
```

Filling a 2D array to a 1D array is a simple (nested) for loop, and back again too.

```
[403, 103, 203, 405 ...]
```

Then, once you have such numbers in a 1D array, just sort it e.g. by Quicksort.

For copying back 1D to 2D, you should have a rule for which number belongs to which row. The transformation for numbers back would be:

```
(x/y) = ( floor(n/100) / n%100 )
```

Sorting a 2D structure *in general*, with *general* criteria, may not be that easy. But in this case, this approach will work. It has been used on other occasions:

[Sorting with 2D Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13372899/sorting-with-2d-arrays)

Comment: actually I am having trouble with how to transfer the 1D back to 2D. Besides quick sort is really hard to implement in MIPS. MIPS sucks!!!!!!! Which means I still have to use bubble sort and I need to think of a better algorithm.

Comment: 1D -> 2D: Is it because you wish so keep some gaps for the "diamond structure", or is it unclear how to decide which row the values belong? - Quicksort: C'mon, that's morning gym ;-D Maybe CombSort is less braing mangling yet faster: [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_sort)

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. Just to make it clear here, I am doing this project in assembly environment called MIPS. The MIPS is very stupid and you have to write a tons of code for a simple bubble sort (or quick sort) as you see above. I can think of many ways to sort this array in C but most of them are hard to be implemented in MIPS. So I am trying to find cleverer algorithm to finish this project(which means fewer steps in MIPS). BTW CombSort is very interesting. I am going to try that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
    SortDiamond:        addi    $01, $00, Array     # set memory base
            swi 521         # create sort diamond and update memory
            addi    $06, $00, 6     # constant 6
            addi    $07, $00, 12        # constant 12
            addi    $12, $00, 0     # counter inner
            addi    $21, $00, 0     # counter in bubble
            addi    $22, $00, 0     # bs counter    

bigloop:        addi    $20, $01, 72        # find the address first element to sort(row)
            addi    $26, $20, 0
            addi    $10, $00, 1     # i starts from 1       
            addi    $11, $00, 2     # sort times
            addi    $23, $00, 2

bsrow:          lw  $17, 0($26)
            lw  $18, 4($26)
            andi    $27, $17, 0x003F    
            andi    $28, $18, 0x003F
            slt $19, $28, $27
            beq $19, $00, go
            sw  $17, 4($26)
            sw  $18, 0($26)
            addi    $22, $00, 1     # this is the indicator of bubble sort

go:         addi    $26, $26, 4
            addi    $21, $21, 1
            bne $21, $23, bsrow 

loopi:          addi    $12, $12, 1
            addi    $26, $20, 0
            addi    $23, $23, -1
            addi    $21, $00, 0
            beq $22, $00, loopj     # jump if it doesn't do bubble sort in one loop
            bne $12, $11, bsrow

loopj:          addi    $10, $10, 1     # i++       
            addi    $22, $00, 0     # reinitialize counter
            slti    $19, $10, 7     # find next row
            beq $19, $00, great     # if i<7 next address is 48+ current
            sll $11, $10, 1
            addi    $20, $20, 48
            j   less

great:          sub $11, $07, $10
            sll $11, $11, 1
            addi    $20, $20, 56

less:           addi    $23, $11, 0     
            addi    $26, $20, 0
            addi    $12, $00, 0
            bne $10, $07, bsrow                 
            addi    $20, $01, 264
            addi    $26, $20, 0
            addi    $10, $00, 1 
            addi    $23, $00, 2
            addi    $11, $00, 2

bscol:          lw  $17, 0($26)
            lw  $18, 52($26)
            slt $19, $18, $17
            beq $19, $00, go1
            sw  $17, 52($26)
            sw  $18, 0($26)
            addi    $22, $00, 1

go1:            addi    $26, $26, 52
            addi    $21, $21, 1
            bne $21, $23, bscol

loopi1:         addi    $12, $12, 1
            addi    $26, $20, 0
            addi    $23, $23, -1
            addi    $21, $00, 0
            beq $22, $00, loopj1
            bne $12, $11, bscol

loopj1:         addi    $10, $10, 1
            addi    $22, $00, 0
            slti    $19, $10, 7
            beq $19, $00, great1
            sll $11, $10, 1
            addi    $20, $20, -48
            j   less1

great1:         sub $11, $07, $10
            sll $11, $11, 1
            addi    $20, $20, 56

less1:          addi    $23, $11, 0     
            addi    $26, $20, 0
            addi    $12, $00, 0
            bne $10, $07, bscol
            swi     522
            bne $02, $00, bigloop 
            swi 523         # redisplay diamond
            jr  $31         # return to caller
```